# Javascript Absolute Positioning

Tags: javascript, layer

I am trying to create a new div layer using JavaScript that can be absolutely positioned on the page after page load.

My code is as follows:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showLayer() {
var myLayer = document.createElement('div');
myLayer.id = 'bookingLayer';
myLayer.style.position = 'absolute';
myLayer.style.x = 10;
myLayer.style.y = 10;
myLayer.style.width = 300;
myLayer.style.height = 300;
myLayer.style.padding = '10px';
myLayer.style.background = '#00ff00';
myLayer.style.display = 'block';
myLayer.style.zIndex = 99;
myLayer.innerHTML = 'This is the layer created by the JavaScript.';
document.body.appendChild(myLayer);
}
</script>
</head><body bgcolor=red>This is the normal HTML content.
<script type="text/javascript"> 
showLayer();
</script>
</body></html>
```

The page can be seen [here](http://js.yachting.org/test.asp).

The problem I am having is that the div is sitting after the original body content rather than over it on a new layer. How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try with this instead:

```
var myLayer = document.createElement('div');
myLayer.id = 'bookingLayer';
myLayer.style.position = 'absolute';
myLayer.style.left = '10px';
myLayer.style.top = '10px';
myLayer.style.width = '300px';
myLayer.style.height = '300px';
myLayer.style.padding = '10px';
myLayer.style.background = '#00ff00';
myLayer.innerHTML = 'This is the layer created by the JavaScript.';
document.body.appendChild(myLayer);
```

The reason it was not working is that you used `x` and `y` css properties (which don't exist) instead of `left` and `top`. Also, for left, top, width, height you had to specify a unit (e.g. `px` for pixels).

Comment: Thanks. As you can possibly guess I am more used to the syntax of other languages. It is working nicely now.

Answer (score 0):

Try these,

- Set the position using top and left rather than x and y.
- An absolute positioned element needs to be contained inside something that also has a position style.  The usual trick is to create a container with position: relative.
- You should be setting styles such as width, height, top, left etc with + 'px'.
- You don't need to set display: block for the div as it is already a block element.

Comment: #2 Not true. The `position` of it's parent only determines how the coordinates will be decided.